# HTTP Error while uploading image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, http-error

I am using wordpress 4.7.2 and php version 7.0. I am getting `http error` while uploading image. I have tried following:-

```
try 1:-
    <IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
    </IfModule>

try2:-
    <FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
    </FilesMatch>
try 3:-
   AddType x-mapp-php5 .php 

try 4:-
    SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1

try 5:- 
    add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
    function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
  }
```

I have deactivated and reactive all plugins,increased upload file size in `wp-config.php` file but nothings works.

Comment: have you checked the file and folder permissions for the images folder as well as the website files and folders. [See this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: yes i have checked, its 777. its working fine for small images. My image dimension is 801x563, which was fail to upload and got that http error.

Comment: Resolved my issue. its the hosting problem, host provider resolved the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the error won't be solved by editing `wp-config.php`, because I had the same error before and solved it by editing `.htaccess`.

Here is what working for me:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
    # WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300

    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 20M
    php_value max_input_time 300

    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case solved by **switching off Adblocker plugin** in  browser